# jQuery mCustomScrollbar not working on ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $(window).load(function(){
                $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{
                        enable:true
                    }
                });

// ajax code
function beauty_of_ceylon() {
  $('.content-text').html('<p style="position:absolute;"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /></p>');
  $('.content-text').load("packages/beauty-of-ceylon.php");
}
```

Comment: What is "#content_1" id , in your code ?

Comment: It's a content div to scroller

Comment: It's work fine when include. But after loading via ajax it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.content-text').load("packages/beauty-of-ceylon.php", function () {
    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
            enable:true
        }
    });
    $content = '<button id="update" onclick="$('#content_1').mCustomScrollbar('update');" style="display:none"></button>';
    $('.content-text').append($content);
    setTimeout("$('#update').click();",10);
});
```

It work for me :D

Answer (score 12):

I did this:

Destroy it when ajax before send and clear your div. Please check comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".YOUR-CONTENT-DIV").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme:"dark",
    });
    
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "YOUR AJAX URL",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".YOUR-CONTENT-DIV").mCustomScrollbar("destroy"); //Destroy
            $('.YOUR-CONTENT-DIV').html('<div class="loading">Loading ...</div>'); //clear html because it will show normal scroll bar
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.YOUR-CONTENT-DIV').html(data);
        },
        complete: function () { 
            $(".YOUR-CONTENT-DIV").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme:"dark",
            });               
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Clearing the div is super important and was the step I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe `.load()` is asynchronous, which means it continues running the script during the `.load()` call. So you have to call the mCustomScrollbar in the callback function, otherwise the content won't be there yet. So try this

```
$('.content-text').load("packages/beauty-of-ceylon.php", function () {
    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollButtons:{
            enable:true
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while so I'm guessing that you found a solution already. If not, your code is correct, to one point. After you do a `.load`, use it's callback function to initiate this command:

```
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar("update");
```

On their website it says that whenever you update the content, you must call this function so the mCustomScrollbar recalculates height of content, scrollbar etc.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 1):

Simply Embed the script into the JSON/AJAX call content, such as:

1.JSON/AJAX back-end script (myscript.vendor, such as Ruby, PHP...)

```
var myHTMLContent = '<script>
    $(".popover-n-content").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme:"dark",
        scrollInertia:100
    });
    </script>
    <div>

    <-- Manipulate -->
    <other_html_tags>
    ...
    </other_html_tags>
    </div>';
```

2.Calling the script "myscript.vendor"

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/get/myscript.vendor",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#data').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of destroy the `mCustomScrollbar`.

`$(".YOUR-CONTENT-DIV").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");`

Put the your `HTML` data

`$('.YOUR-CONTENT-DIV').html('HTML');`

Create a `mCustomScrollbar` for `div`

```
setTimeout(function() {

$(".YOUR-CONTENT-DIV").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"dark"
  });
}, 300);
```

Answer (score 1):

please see this [reference](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/228#issuecomment-304718085)

codes:

```
  $('#content_1').mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
  $('#content_1').append('some text or another things');
  $('#content_1').mCustomScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you load pages through ajax window.load wont be called , so mCustomScrollBar is not initialized.when page loads by ajax document ready will be triggered.

try the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                }
            });
});
```