# jQuery mCustomScrollbar disappears after Ajax reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, scrollbar

like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231199/jquery-mcustomscrollbar-not-working-on-ajax-content/24632046#24632046) written I have a problem with jQuery mCustomScrollbar. 
Binding the scrollbar at the first load works fine.

```
$("#contenDiv").load("dummytext.php", function() {
   $("#contenDiv").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "light",
        alwaysShowScrollbar: 1
      });
 });
```

But when I reload the Divs content the mCustomScrollbar disappears, althougt I call the "update" method.

```
$("#loadbutton").click(function() {
    $("#contenDiv").load("dummytext.php", function() {
        $(this).mCustomScrollbar("update");
    });
});
```

I've also been trying to work with on() and delegate() methods but they don't recognize the jquery Ajax load() event.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a fix for your problem?

Comment: if you solved the issue, please update